# Looking for a (pseudo) XSLT preprocessor/templater to make it less verbose

Tags: xslt, ide, preprocessor, template-engine, verbose

Does anybody know of a preprocessor for XSLT to make it less verbose? Something like what [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is to CSS, a little proggy that will take light syntax:

```
"/":
{
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>My book collection</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  {@ "//media"}
  {@ quantity = calc_abs_value("//total_quantity")}
  Price : {@ multiply(price:"//item[@selected='true'][@price]",qty  :$quantity) }
  </body>  
 </html>
}

"media[@type='book']":
{
 <div id="{@id}">
 {title} by {author} published in {published_date}
 </div>
}

function calc_abs_value(value)
{
 if ($value < 0) {- $value} else {$value}
}

function multiply(price,qty:"1")
{
 switch 
 {
  "$qty = 1" : $price * $qty 
  "$qty < 5" : $price * $qty * 0.95 
  "$price * $qty < 0" : 0
  default : 0
 }
}
```

and turn this into far-less readable XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
      <head>
      <title>My book collection</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//media" />
      <xsl:variable name="quantity"><xsl:call-template name="calc_abs_value">
      <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select="//total_quantity" /></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
      Price : <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
      <xsl:with-param name="price"><xsl:value-of select="//item[@selected='true'][@price]" /></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="qty"><xsl:value-of select="$quantity" /></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
      </body>  
     </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="media[@type='book']">
    {
     <div id="{@id}">
     <xsl:value-of select="title" /> by <xsl:value-of select="author" /> published in <xsl:value-of select="published_date" />
     </div>
    }
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="calc_abs_value">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$value < 0">
       - <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am too lazy to write the XSLT form of multiply but I'm sure you already figured out what I mean.

Or is there an IDE that is more XSLT aware than others, e.g it displays `{author}` but expands to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="author" />
```

when you click it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be better ask: *how to **[DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)** the XSLT?*

You might be interested in some practical example such as [**YSLT**](http://fdik.org/yml/yslt) based on [**YML**](http://fdik.org/yml) concept.

**NOTE** It should be better not to convert/preprocess the code to get an XSLT transform at all; instead, just emulate the way a processor parses the input document and use your own DSL.

---

You can also write your own DSL. You should use some scripting language which really makes DSL concept easy, as, for example, **ruby**. In **ruby**, you can achieve something very nice and clean like:

```
match "/" do
 value-of :foo
end
```

which could work as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Another thing that worth to be mentioned is **templating languages** like [**erb**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/). This is I think the only feasible alternative to XSLT in general (even if alternative here is a big compromise and you get lost very soon with procedural manipulation of nodes).

---

**Note**

***I love XSLT verbosity*** and, because of this verbosity, I think XSLT code **is much more readable** then any other language (once you understand how templates work).

I **don't** recommend to search something for converting some different markup to XSLT code. Your final XSLT code will **loose of readbility** and its code **will not be optimal** at all.

Comment: Look promising, will have a look at it. Being verbose doesn't make a language more readable it just make it less ambiguous. I already produce suboptimal code without DSL :) so that's not a big point.

Comment: By having a quick look at a program you (I) can guess the logic (loops, var settings). 
I can't do that with xsl :  my eyes/brain can't integrate so much text. 
Maybe just a matter of practicing or the lack of a good IDE whith nice syntax highligthing.
But I suspect this is a bit like long phrases : 
they may be clearer when you carefully read them, but after some you get headaches.

Comment: It's not the lack of a good IDE. You need only highlighting and indentation. I think your concerns are much related to the fact that you may come from not-functional programming language. In XSLT you normally avoid _loops_ or _var settings_.

Comment: You might also be interested in templating language like erb, as referenced in the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few attempts to do this over the years but none that seems to have been used by anyone other than its originator. I think, frankly, the verbosity of XSLT is something you quickly get used to. XSLT 2.0 is of course far less verbose than 1.0.

Comment: xslt2 is not supported by .net AFAIK (shame on you MS), so it's a no-go for me. Because of that I didn't consider using it despite it looks easier to read than xslt1 (had a quick look at it when I reinvent Muenchian on my own). My concern is not much about lack of functionnality (exslt exists and I don't make complex xslt) but much about lack of readability. I'll be glad you point me at those attempts

Comment: Here's one: http://www.zanthan.com/ajm/xsltxt/ And another: http://code.google.com/p/compactxml/ And a third: http://www.wilmott.ca/rxslt/rxslt.html And I've seen many others over the years. They are all as dead as dodos.

Answer (score 1):

At Balisage last week Evan Lenz presented yet another attempt, called Carrot: this time not just a compact syntax for XSLT but a language that attempts to provide the union of XSLT and XQuery. Looks interesting, but I don't think there's an implementation yet (and I'd be surprised if it catches on...)

Comment: wow! It looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Processing-instructions can be used to implement macros, such as in this [unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387327/1113772) on Docbook.

```
Template:
<?echo gal?>

Code:
<xsl:variable name="gal" select="'howdy'"/>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('echo')">
  <xsl:value-of select="//xsl:variable/@select[../@name=current()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

There's also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792707/is-there-any-way-to-call-xslt-templates-inline/8763014#8763014) which covers simplified parameter passing.

[XMLPreprocess](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) or [oXML](http://www.o-xml.org/examples/) may also be of interest as well.

Comment: looks interesting. Will have to investigate further if it really improves readability (the use of the variable is a bit unclear. is it global ? local ?). it looks like it will help for inlinecontent :  <?echo test?> is clearer than <call-template name="echo"><xsl:with-param>test</..></..> but I'm not sure about processing directives in function.