# PHP and XSLT: extending the processor

Tags: php, xslt

I need to extend XSLT processor in PHP with my own tags and functions. I found some APIs, but these APIs is still not what I need.

1) http://php.net/manual/ru/book.xsl.php - quite simple API, but I can extend functions only (registerPHPFunctions), not tags.

2) http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xslt.php - nice and simple, I can extend whatever I need (xslt_set_sax_handlers), but, here we go - another problem. Introduction (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xslt.php) says: "This extension has been moved to the » PECL repository and is no longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 5.0.0.". Okay, I'm navigating to pecl.php.net ->  Search Packages -> XSLT -> No results found -> o_O

So, looks like the good API was deprecated, and the bad API doesn't satisfy my needs. What can you recomend guys? I need a PHP XSLT processor where I can extend or override everything that can be extended or overridden like the "2)" above does. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you said what you are trying to achieve. You want to add extension elements to XSLT, I take it, but why exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I'm interested in hearing your functional requirements also. PHP has quite a lot of nice XML parsing functionality to complement the usual SAX/DOM/XSL features. You may find that what you need is already there unless your solution absolutely must be XSL.

Comment: Hey guys. I'm writing new version of my website engine. The essense of the engine - is XSLT processor + tag/function extensions + transparent data binding (like MySQL). So, I need a way to write custom PHP handlers for several XML tags. Currently I use regexp replace to achive custom XML tags behavior, but it has a set of problems. For example - nested structures handling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrade PHP XSLT processor to XSLT 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873996/upgrade-php-xslt-processor-to-xslt-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses `libxslt` as its default processor, and `libexslt` as its extension processor. Here is the API documentation:

- [EXSLT API Symbols](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/EXSLT/APIsymbols.html)
- [LibXSLT Macros](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/html/libxslt-xsltexports.html)
- [LibXSLT Source](http://www.xmlsoft.org/sources/)
- [LibXSLT Git Repo](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxslt/tree/)

In addition, `libxslt`already supports an [eval extension](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxslt/tree/tests/extensions/evaluate.xsl), which may serve your purposes.

There's also built-in macros available via `xsl:processing-instruction` which match the shorthand delimiters of PHP:

- [Is there any way to call XSLT templates inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792707/is-there-any-way-to-call-xslt-templates-inline/8763014#8763014)
- [Looking for a (pseudo) XSLT preprocessor/templater to make it less verbose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816770/looking-for-a-pseudo-xslt-preprocessor-templater-to-make-it-less-verbose/13383122#13383122)
- [Multi layer conditional wrap HTML with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365816/multi-layer-conditional-wrap-html-with-xslt/18865513#18865513)

And the [registerPHPFunctions](https://github.com/evnix/go-php-parser/blob/master/testdata/fuzzdir/corpus/ext_xsl_tests_xsltprocessor_registerPHPFunctions-array-multiple.php) method.

A transformation can pass a XPath expression as an argument to a function in a custom namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:js="urn:livescript"
  extension-element-prefixes="js"
>

  <xsl:variable name="source" select="//"/>

  <xsl:template match="json">
    <xsl:value-of select="livescript:JSON($source)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The function links to an external transformation which computes the XPath result and returns the result by using a callback.

**References**

- [XSLTProcessor::hasExsltSupport](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.hasexsltsupport.php)
- [XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php)
- [EXSLT for MSXML](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1261)
- [MDN: EXSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/EXSLT)
- [comlibxml](http://comlibxml.mozdev.org)
- [W3C: HTML/XML Utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/)